# Browser back button navigates to login page when user is still logged in

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, back

I have a website that is mostly built in .NET MVC. I say mostly because the login page is done using web forms. The login page uses forms authentication. The issue is that when I use the browser back button, it navigates back to the login page when the user is still authenticated. How can I stop this from happening?

I tried to set the cache to null on load of the login page, but no luck:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Let me know if there is any code that may be helpful. I've never dealt with this issue before and I'm not sure what would help.

Comment: Why is this a problem? This is expected behaviour from browser. You were on one page, you moved to another - previous page is saved in browser history. You hit Back button in browser, you get back to the previuos page. Is there really a problem you should solve?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function that checks if they are logged in and if they are redirect them to the 'members' only page. I cannot post any code because I am on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the "no cache on browser back" behavior on all pages then you should put it in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - disabling output cache (via attribute OutputCache) for action method which is responsible to show login page and also add condition which checks that user is already logged in:

```
public partial class AccountController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
            return View(model);
        }
}
```